# Docker desktop kubernetes add node

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I  running docker desktop with kubernetes option turned on. I have one node called docker-for-dektop.
Now i have created a new ubuntu docker container. I want to add this container to my kubernetes cluster. Can be done? how can i do it?

Comment: You need to create a kubernetes deployment yaml and use kubectl comman to run this container on kubernetes cluster. Follow this [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/deploy-app/deploy-intro/) for more details

Comment: this will create an app inside a existent node. I need to create a new node and run the container inside this new node. I want to run a cluster with at lease 3 nodes. This can be done with docker (not enterprise version)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you cannot add a node to Docker for Desktop with Kubernetes enabled.

Docker for Desktop is a single-node Kubernetes or Docker Swarm cluster, you might try using [kubernetes-the-hard-way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) as this explains how to setup a cluster and add nodes manually without the use of [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

But I don't think this might work as there will be a lot of issues with setting up the network to work correctly.

You can also use the instructions on how to [install kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/) with kubelet and kubectl on Linux machine and adding a node using `kubeadm join`.